# Coffeescript equivalent of zip(*dict.items()) from Python

Tags: python, coffeescript

What is the Coffeescript equivalent of `zip(*dict.items())` from Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple - if you have an object `dict`,

```
[Object.keys(dict), Object.values(dict)]
```

Comment: This is why even though we've moved on to ES 6 at work I still miss coffeescript...

Comment: @JaredSmith Huh? This is *identical* in ES6.

Comment: Then your version doesn't do what I thought it did (and indeed, it doesn't I just tested). `zip` should return an array of tuples (in the form `[[v1, k1], [v2, k2]]` to be equivalent to the python in the question), not an array of keys and an array of values. I would have expected the output to be that for zip in any language (modulo python's reversing of the usual order).

Comment: A correct (although naive) answer in coffeescript would be something like `[[v, k] for k, v of object]`.

Comment: Re-check your Python. I did what you asked; you may not have asked what you wanted to know. `dict.items()` will return `[(k1, v1), (k2, v2)]`, splat will make it into `zip((k1, v1), (k2, v2))`, which evaluates to `[(k1, k2), (v1, v2)]`. Since JS does not have tuples, an array of keys and an array of values - what I posted - is the closest you can get. If you wanted a list of value-and-key pairs, the correct Python is `[(v, k) for k, v in dict.iteritems()]`, which cleanly translates into the CoffeeScript you posted - no `zip`.